# Can fbprophet deal with hourly data? And how to deal with hourly data?

Tags: facebook

fbprophet can perfectly deal with daily data. Can it deal with hourly data?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can. You just need to specify the `freq` parameter with 'h' when you call function `make_future_dataframe`.

Example code:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'ds': pd.date_range('2017-01-01 00:00:00', periods=240, freq='h'), 'y': np.random.uniform(0, 1, 240)})
pp = Prophet()
pp.fit(test)

abc = pp.make_future_dataframe(periods=240, freq='h')
ff = pp.predict(abc)
pp.plot(ff)
```

Comment: i tested your example, and i dont se it working with latest prophet package... could you plelase share link to graph ?

Comment: I have tested the above code on latest version of prophet (0.1.1) and it still works. Although, because prophet doesn't have daily seasonality components, the prediction output for all different hours in the same day will be the same, so there's little to no value of doing it.